# Funcion JavaScript funciona sólo una vez Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estoy desarrollando un script para abrir una pasarela en un iframe, la he adaptado a mis necesidades y hasta el momento funciona perfecto pero cuando le doy a cerrar no vuelve a funcionar por segunda vez... porque desaparecen los controles... debe ser una tontería de sintaxis, apreciaría ayuda!

El código lo saqué de aquí y lo edite un poco: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781628/how-to-load-iframe-content-in-popup-div

EDIT: Tema solucionado, gracias a @TheWoodStudio

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".popup").hide();
    $(".openpop").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr('href'));
        $(".links").fadeOut('slow');
        $(".popup").fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".controles").fadeOut('slow');
  $(".popup").fadeOut('slow');
        $(".links").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.payframe {
 border: 3px solid orange;
 border-radius: 6px;
 max-width: 770px;
 min-height: 680px;
}

.close {
 clear:both; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
<a class="openpop" href="https://www.webpay.cl/portalpagodirecto/pages/institucion.jsf?idEstablecimiento=27558675"><p style="text-align: center;">

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-3842 size-full" src="https://estaticos.bellpro.cl/2017/09/Pago-Facil-WebPayCLPNG.png" alt="" width="300" height="300" />

</div>


<div class="popup" align="center">

 <div class="controles">
   <a href="#" class="close">Cancelar Pago</a> - 
    <a href="https://www.webpay.cl/portalpagodirecto/pages/institucion.jsf?idEstablecimiento=27558675" target="_blank" class="close">Abrir en una nueva pestaña</a>
    </div>
    
<iframe src="" width="770" marginwidth="0" height="680" marginheight="0" align="middle" scrolling="Yes" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" class="payframe" allowtransparency="true" application="true">
<p>Su navegador no está actualizado....</p>
</iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Puede ser que la clase en la que están los controles, es decir ".controles" tenga el evento ".fadeOut('slow')" y nunca le estás diciendo que reaparezca, con ".fadeIn".

Comment: @TheWoodStudio muchas gracias acabo de darme cuenta que llevas razón, he eliminado esa linea y ahora funciona pefecto!

Comment: De nada! A veces pasa! Saludos!

Comment: esto generalmente es por la version de jQuery debes verificar con que trabaja el ejemplo para que te funcione o buscar el tutorial para la version que trabajas

Comment: @TheWoodStudio Añade lo que le dijiste como respuesta, para que el pueda marcar la pregunta como solucionada.

Comment: Ya está mi comentario como respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser que la clase en la que están los controles, es decir ".controles" tenga el evento ".fadeOut('slow')" y nunca le estás diciendo que reaparezca, con ".fadeIn()".